# Multi-Connection bluetooth application

Tags: java, bluetooth, midp-2.0

I am developing a J2ME MIDP 2.0 game that can can be played over bluetooth,
it is similar to tic tac toe where players exchange turns until the game is over,
the problem is that i want to give the both players the ability to restart the game or quit
at any time but i only have one connection for transferring game related data, and i wonder if i could have two separate connections between the two devices at the same time, one for eg. game management (restart, quit, etc ..) and the other for game data to separate the logic.
or you could put it this way : is it possible to have multiple bluetooth connections between two MIDP devices at the same time ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think for bluetooth.Via j2me mobile application the Midp device is connected at most only one  device and at most at a time only one connection is enabled.So there is no chance of going to multiple connections.